# rendering html and css on flask using python application via raspberry pi

Tags: python, html, css, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to display the DHT11 sensor readings on any remote device by creating a web-server using flask, on Python via Raspberry Pi.
I was thinking about making the readings look more visually appealing by using HTML and CSS.

Any idea how I can add a title and background color to the web-page whilst display the results?

Thanks!

This is the code I'm currently using in the python application:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import Adafruit_DHT

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_humidity_and_temperature_from_DHT11():

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, 4)
return jsonify({'humidity': humidity, 'temperature': temperature})

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='12345')
```

Comment: Is the web-page static? Or do you need result to be updated dynamically?

Comment: I update the webpage manually by refreshing it, and values change when necessary.